# Reiz und seine Synonyme

Tags: word-choice, synonym

> **Reiz:** 
>      1. äußere oder innere Einwirkung auf den Organismus, z. B. auf die Sinnesorgane, die eine bestimmte, nicht vom Willen gesteuerte Reaktion auslöst
>          2.a. von jemandem oder einer Sache ausgehende verlockende Wirkung; Antrieb, Anziehungskraft
>          2.b. Zauber, Anmut, Schönheit, Charme
>
> **Anreiz:** etwas, was jemandes Interesse erregt, ihn motiviert, etwas zu tun; Antrieb
>
> **Triebfeder:** Feder (3), die den Antrieb (1) von etwas bewirkt [hier geht es um die übertragene Bedeutung]
>
> **Stimulus:** 
>       1. (Psychologie) (eine unwillkürliche Reaktion auslösender) Reiz 
>       2. (bildungssprachlich) Anreiz
>
> **Antrieb:** 
>       1. Triebkraft, bewegende Kraft
>       2. Anreiz, Impuls, Beweggrund, innere Triebfeder

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Synonymem?

Meine Theorie: Stimulus ist nur ein kluges Wort für Reiz/Anreiz. Aber über den Rest habe ich keine Ahnung. Und die Definitionen beziehen sich aufeinander (es ist deshalb sehr schwierig, sich nur auf zwei-drei Synonyme beruhen zu lassen)

Comment: Vielleicht interessant https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/reiz-gereizt-reizend-meaning/   (auf Englisch)

Comment: Du kannst [synonyme.woxikon.de] nutzen, um Synonyme zu finden. You can use [synonyme.woxikon.de] to look for synonyms [![][img]][synonyme.woxikon.de] [synonyme.woxikon.de]: http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/trieb.php
[img]: https://i.imgur.com/xc5n2Sz.png

Comment: Das sind *keine* Synonyme. Sie sind zu unterschiedlich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Reiz

Ein Reiz ist zunächst mal ganz allgemein ein Ereignis, das in einem belebten Organismus eine Reaktion hervorruft. Ein Beispiel: Schallwellen dringen bis zum Innenohr eines Tieres oder Menschen vor und versetzen dort die Fortsätze der Haarzellen in mikroskopisch kleine Bewegungen. Daraufhin erzeugen diese Zellen ein elektrisches Signal, das an andere Nervenzellen weitergeleitet wird. Hier sind die Schallwellen der Reiz, der in den Haarzellen eine Reaktion auslöst. Der Schall *reizt* diese Sinneszellen.

Ebenso kann Licht, das beständig auf die Rinde eines Baumes fällt, ein Reiz sein, der zur Ausbildung eines Triebes an der beleuchteten Stelle führt, aus der sich später vielleicht ein ganzer Ast entwickelt. Hier kommt die Reaktion auf den Reiz ganz ohne ein Nervensystem aus. Auch Tiere können biochemisch auf Reize reagieren.

Bei Tieren und Menschen löst ein Reiz häufig auch eine Wahrnehmung aus. Das ist die psychologische Variante den Begriff »Reiz« zu definieren, während die vorangegangene jene der Physiologen ist.

Diese Erklärung umfasst aber nur die »Hardware«-Ebene. Das Wort »Reiz« hat aber auch auf einer höheren Ebene eine Bedeutung:

Als »Reiz« bezeichnet man auch die Ausstrahlung z.B. einer Person, etwa in diesem Satz:

> Von Claudia geht ein ganz besonderer Reiz aus.

Damit ist gemeint, dass Claudia durch ihr Auftreten, durch ihre persönliche Art und vielleicht auch durch ihre äußere Erscheinung etwas bei anderen Menschen bewirkt, das bei anderen Personen nicht der Fall ist. Und dieses »etwas«, das da wirkt, ist etwas positives, das Sympathie für Claudia hervorruft.
Schweißgeruch wäre zwar auch ein Beispiel für etwas, das von Claudia ausgehen könnte und bei anderen Menschen eine Reaktion bewirkt, das wäre aber eine negative Wirkung, und das ist damit nicht gemeint. (Höchstens scherzhaft)

### Anreiz

Das ist auch ein Reiz, der von einer Sache ausgeht, aber dieser Reiz hat das Potenzial eine oder mehrere Personen dazu zu motivieren etwas bestimmtes zu tun. Mit »Anreiz« ist aber nicht nur die Verlockung, der von der Sache ausgeht, gemeint, sondern auch die verlockende Sache selbst.

Ein Anreiz ist also ein Motivator. Meist ist ein Anreiz die Belohnung, von der man sich erhofft, dass man sie für die Absolvierung einer mühsamen oder unangenehmen Tätigkeit erhält.

Für eine Fußballmannschaft kann der Meistertitel samt dem damit verbundenen Ruhm und der Verehrung durch die Fans sein. Für einen Schüler kann das Sternchen, dass die Lehrerin bei guten Leistungen als Zeichen ihrer Anerkennung ins Schulheft malt, der Anreiz sein, zuhause stundenlang zu üben oder zu lernen.

### Triebfeder, Antrieb

Motoren brauchen Energie um etwas in Bewegung zu versetzen. Eine Art Energie so zu speichern, dass sie einen Motor antreiben kann, ist eine Spiralfeder (sie besteht meist aus einem Metallband), die durch Verdrehen gespannt (»aufgezogen«) wird. Diese Spiralfeder, die etwas antreiben kann, nennt man eine Triebfeder. Mechanische Uhren und altes Spielzeug sind Beispiele für Gegenstände, deren Motor und Energiespeicher eine Triebfeder ist.

Das Wort »antreiben« ist schon gefallen, und tatsächlich ist eine Triebfeder nur eine spezielle Art eines Antriebes. Ein Benzinmotor wäre auch ein Antrieb, aber er ist keine Triebfeder.

Im übertragenen Sinn sind die beiden Begriffe aber Synonyme, wobei »Triebfeder« - wie auch der ursprünglich gemeinte Gegenstand - veraltet ist und selten verwendet wird.

Der Antrieb ist das, wann einen Menschen vorwärts treibt. Er ist das Bedürfnis, ein Ziel zu erreichen. Der Antrieb ist das, was häufig auf das Wahrnehmen eines Anreizes folgt.

Wer einen Wettkampf gewinnt, darf mit einem Preisgeld, mit Anerkennung und mit Ruhm rechnen. Diese drei Dinge (Preisgeld, Anerkennung und Ruhm) sind der **Anreiz**. Dieser Anreiz ruft in unterschiedlichen Personen ein unterschiedlich starkes Bedürfnis hervor, diese Dinge zu erlangen, doch davor steht die Mühe, sich auf einen Wettkampf vorzubereiten, verbunden mit der Ungewissheit ob man diesen Wettkampf auch gewinnen wird.

Einige Menschen werden sich entscheiden, die Mühe und Ungewissheit auf sich zu nehmen. Sie haben genug **Antrieb**, um den Weg zu gehen, der notwendig ist, um das Ziel zu erreichen. Andere werden befinden, dass die Mühen und die Ungewissheit zu groß sind, oder dass der Anreiz zu klein ist um diesen Weg zu gehen. Ihnen fehlt dann der nötige Antrieb.

### Stimulus

Dieses lateinische Wort hat drei Bedeutungen:

1. Der Stimulus ist ein einzelner Stachel, ein Sporn oder auch eine Peitsche, die mit kleinen Stacheln besetzt ist. Häufig waren diese Gegenstände auch noch mit Widerhaken versehen. Benutzt wurden sie um Arbeitstiere und Sklaven anzutreiben (anspornen) oder zu bestrafen.
2. Als Stimulus bezeichneten die alten Römer aber auch die innere Unruhe, die einen zu etwas treibt. Es war der Überbegriff für Eifersucht, Wut und Raserei.
3. Der Stimulus war aber auch ein von außen kommender **Anreiz**, der einen dazu **antrieb** etwas bestimmtes zu tun.

Heute hat »Stimulus« die Bedeutung von »Reiz«. Umgangssprachlich wird das Wort nur selten benutzt. Als Fachbegriff kommt es vor allen in den beiden folgenden Disziplinen vor:

**Physiologie**
Ein Stimulus ist ein **Reiz**, der bei einem Lebewesen eine Reaktion hervorrufen kann.

**Psychologie**
Ein Stimulus ist ein **Reiz**, der zu einer Wahrnehmung führt.

Comment: Tolle Antwort. Hätten Sie diese  früher geschrieben, so hätte ich sie höchstens um Zitate erweitert.

Comment: @Ludi: Ich hatte früher leider keine Zeit für diese ausführliche Antwort, und kurze Antworten gab es ja schon.

Answer (score 5):

Das breitere Spektrum der Bedeutungen von "Reiz" wird schon aus den Begleitinformationen zur Frage deutlich. So kann nur Reiz in der Bedeutung "Zauber", "Charme" verwendet werden.

> «Sie las die Worte so wie er sie zu sprechen pflegte, mit der weichen und musikalischen Betonung seiner Stimme, sie suchte in ihren Namen den heimlich-süßen Reiz zu legen, den nur die Sprache der Zärtlichkeit geben kann.»
>   *Stefan Zweig*, **Die Liebe der Erika Ewald**

Richtig wurde auch schon bemerkt wo "Stimulus" verwand wird. Ich will mich nun der Differenzierung derjenigen Begriffe widmen welche sich ähneln. Diese ist sehr schwierig und ich bin für konstruktive Kritik offen.

Auf die Gefahr hin der Tautologie bezichtigt zu werden, will ich hervorheben, dass der Anreiz ein Reiz ist, der Antrieb dagegen treibt. So würde ich in folgendem Zitat, welches beschreibt wie der Autor zu etwas bewegt wurde, nicht "Anreiz" verwenden.

> «So bestellte ich einen zweiten; erst als ich den dritten verlangte, entdeckte ich den unbewußten Antrieb: ich wollte mir Mut antrinken, um dort draußen nicht feig zu werden oder sentimental.»
>   *Stefan Zweig*,**Ungeduld des Herzens**

Und in folgendem niemals Antrieb:

> «Immer aber bedarf ich, um Vergangenes sinnlich zu sehen und zu fühlen, eines sinnlichen Anreizes, eines winzigen Helfers aus der Wirklichkeit.»
>   Stefan Zweig*,**Ungeduld des Herzens**,

denn es geht um einen Reiz.

Vielleicht hilft folgendes Beispiel:

> Es fehlte mir nicht an Anreizen die Doktorarbeit zu vollenden. Seit mir mein Professor so übel mitgespielt hatte fehlte es mir jedoch an jeglichem Antrieb.

Soweit ist die Sache recht klar. Große Schwierigkeiten aber bereitet mir die Einordnung des Begriffes "Triebfeder". Dieser gehört zwar offensichtlich zu den "Antrieben", wird aber nur in bestimmten Fällen benutzt welche klar zu benennen mir sehr schwer fällt. Ich bin versucht die Triebfeder als maßgeblichen und oft nachhaltigeren Antrieb zu definieren, wie er hier vorliegt:

> «Hass war die eigentliche Triebfeder (der eigentliche Beweggrund) zu diesem Verbrechen.»
>   *Duden*
>
> «..., denn wie bei jedem Schwächling ist bei Darnley die Triebfeder aller seiner Handlungen unbefriedigte Eitelkeit.»
>   *Stefan Zweig*,**Maria Stuart**,

Comment: *der Anreiz ein Reiz ist, der Antrieb dagegen treibt.* - und was wäre der Unterschied hier?

Comment: @marmistrz Siehe zum Beispiel das sehr gute Beispiel von Herrn Schölnast. Dort siehst du wie der Anreiz zwar zu etwas reizen kann ohne tatsächlich dazu zu treiben!

Answer (score 1):

Anreiz und Antrieb haben einen (eher) positiven Unterton. Stimulus, wie Du zu Recht bemerkst, wird vor allem im sehr gehobenen oder wissenschaftlichen Sprachgebrauch verwendet.

Reiz ist im Gegensatz zu Anreiz und Antrieb eher neutral, kann also positiv wie negativ (oder auch völlig wertfrei) verwendet werden.

Anreiz und Antrieb unterscheiden sich dahingehend, dass der Antrieb eine tatsächliche Handlung begleitet, der Anreiz hingegen nicht. Wie @Hubert Schölnast zu Recht bemerkt hat, kann ich einen Anreiz haben, etwas zu tun, aber wenn mir der Antrieb fehlt, bleibt es ungetan.

Comment: Nein. Anreiz und Antrieb sind nicht gleichwertig. Man kann eine Sache aus eigenem Antrieb machen, aber nicht aus eigenem Anreiz. Eine ausgelobte Belohnung kann ein Anreiz sein, aber sie ist kein Antrieb. Der Antrieb ist das Bestreben diesen Gewinn zu erzielen, aber nicht der Gewinn selbst. Ich kann ja auch den Anreiz durchaus wahrnehmen, aber zu faul sein, mich dafür anzustrengen. In diesem Fall fehlt mir der Antrieb, obwohl ein Anreiz da ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ein sehr gutes Beispiel!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast da hast Du recht. Was meinst Du: Sollte ich die Antwort löschen oder zugunsten Deines Kommentars stehen lassen?

Comment: @Burki: Nicht löschen. Aber du kannst sie ja editieren, also umschreiben. Wenn dann mein Kommentar nicht mehr zur Antwort passt, werde ich ihn löschen.