# Trieb und seine Synonyme

Tags: word-choice, synonym

[Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23567/reiz-und-seine-synonyme) habe ich nach dem Unterschied zwischen den Synonymen von Reiz gefragt, unter denen standen: *Reiz, Anreiz, Antrieb, Triebfeder und Stimulus*. (Ich habe noch keine Antwort akzeptiert – so gut sind die Antworten :) ). Neulich habe ich noch ein ähnliches Wort gefunden:

> **der Trieb:** 
>       1a. (oft vom Instinkt gesteuerter) innerer Antrieb, der auf die Befriedigung starker, oft lebensnotwendiger Bedürfnisse zielt 
>       1b. (veraltend) Lust, Verlangen, etwas zu tun

Ist *Antrieb* zu *Trieb* wie *Anreiz* zu *Reiz*? Vielleicht ist *Trieb* nur auf den Instinkt beschränkt? Gibt es einen Unterschied im Verhältnis zu den Wörtern aus dem früheren Post?

Comment: Beachte den unterschied zwischen *innerer Antrieb* und *innerer Auftrieb* in den Erläuterungen.

Comment: Ich finde es nicht gut, dass ich die andere Frage nachgucken muss, um diese hier zu beantworten. Ein Verweis ist ok, aber jede Frage sollte für sich stehen können. In Bezug auf "Trieb" vs. "Aufschwung".... "Trieb" is an inner drive (which it is also related to). "Aufschwung" is something completely different. The only overlap is the sense of rising level of intensity.

Comment: Ups... Ich habe Antrieb statt Auftrieb gelesen :) Ich werde gleich Schwung löschen. @Emanuel: Ich habe eine neue Frage gestellt und auf die alte zurückgegriffen, wie auf Meta vorgeschlagen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/903/late-extensions-to-questions-asking-about-differences-between-words?cb=1 . Wenn ich auf einer anderen Art und Weise es schreiben soll, kommentiere bitte in Meta.

Comment: Schreib die Wörter aus dem früheren Post doch einfach in Klammern. Sonst kann man ja gleich fragen "Was ist der Unterschied zwischen schwer und dem Wort aus diesem [link] Post?"

Comment: Du fragst hier übrigens (wenn ich Dich nicht falsch verstanden habe) nicht nach [Synonymen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym), sondern nach [Homonymen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).

Comment: Trieb ist doch synonymisch zu Antrieb, so Duden.

Comment: @Matthias ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass marmistrz nach Synonymen statt nach Homonymen fragt. Dafür sprechen auch gefühlt alle anderen Fragen der Person ;)

Comment: @marmistrz Du zitierst zwei (von mehreren) Bedeutungen des Wortes "Trieb" und nennst sie auch noch "zwei ähnliche Wörter". Deshalb verstehe ich die Frage so, dass Du die beiden Bedeutungen, also die Homonyme, in ihrer unterschiedlichen Bedeutung verstehen willst und dass der Bezug zu "Reiz" und seinen Synonymen dabei irgendwie helfen soll. Ganz klar ist mir aber nicht, was Du eigentlich willst; vor allem der letzte Satz ergibt für mich keinen Sinn.

Comment: Ja, aber diese Bedeutungen von Antrieb sind ganz ähnlich. Und wenn ich 2a. zitiere, meiner Meinung nach soll ich den ganzen Punkt 2 zitieren. Und der letzte Satz "Erkläre mir es so, bitte, damit ich den Unterschied zwischen Trieb und den anderen kennen kann" (dazu muss man nicht jede zwei vergleichen)

Comment: @marmistrz Was meinst Du jetzt mit **2**a und b? Es wird immer wirrer. VTC - unclear what you are asking.

Comment: ***Reiz**: (...) 2.a. von jemandem oder einer Sache ausgehende verlockende Wirkung; Antrieb, Anziehungskraft 2.b. Zauber, Anmut, Schönheit, Charme*. Ich beziehe mich auf die Definitionen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ich habe vergessen, das *zwei* zu ändern. Vgl. originelle Fassung. Ich habe es gerade korrigiert.

Comment: Du kannst [synonyme.woxikon.de] nutzen, um Synonyme zu finden. You can use [synonyme.woxikon.de] to look for synonyms [![][img]][synonyme.woxikon.de] [synonyme.woxikon.de]: http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/trieb.php
[img]: https://i.imgur.com/xc5n2Sz.png

Answer (score 2):

> Ist Antrieb zu Trieb wie Anreiz zu Reiz?

Ja, wenn man vom allgemeinen Sprachverständnis ausgeht.

> Vielleicht ist Trieb nur auf den Instinkt beschränkt?

Vor dem Hintergrund der Homöostase (das Streben des menschlichen Körpers nach einem physiologischen Gleichgewicht) sind Triebe ein innerer Zustand und ein Resultat aus einem Ungleichgewicht der physiologischen Bedürfnisse eines Lebewesens.

Aus psychologischer Sicht liegt der Unterschied von Trieb und Instinkt darin, dass Triebe sich nicht durch bestimmte Handlungen auszeichnen.

Siehe auch:

> *Zwischen Instinkt- und Trieb-Begriff wird oft, vor allem im amerikanischen Schrifttum, nicht genau unterschieden; das deutsche Wort Trieb wird abwechselnd mit instinct oder mit drive übersetzt, und in Rückübersetzungen kommt es zu weiterer Verwirrung. Beide Begriffe sind nur Vorstufen einer wirklichen Klärung, da sie keine Vorstellung über die zugrunde liegenden Gesetzmäßigkeiten vermitteln.*

[Quelle](http://www.psychology48.com/deu/d/instinkt/instinkt.htm)

Comment: Willkommen beim StackExchange der Deutschen Sprache. Wenn Du magst, nimm die [tour], oder schau Dich im [help] um. Viel Spaß!

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst einmal: Wie die fachspezifischen (Psychologie z.B.) Unterscheidungen und Definitionen von den Begriffen lauten, weiß ich nicht.

> Ist *Antrieb* zu *Trieb* wie *Anreiz* zu *Reiz*?

Ja, das ist korrekt.

> Vielleicht ist Trieb nur auf den Instinkt beschränkt?

Trieb klingt für mich mehr nach unbewusstem Drang als nach bewusstem, mag aber auch ab und zu anders verwendet werden, wie zum Beispiel: *Es trieb ihn zur Weißglut.* Wobei wahrscheinlicher scheint, dass *er* sich der Ursache bewusst ist.

Answer (score 0):

Machen wir's mal mit Herrn Freud:

Antrieb kommt vom "Ich" und vom "Über-Ich"
Trieb vom "Es"

Comment: Hast Du dafür eine Quelle?

Answer (score -2):

An bedeutet hin.

An-Trieb
An-Reiz
An-Schub
An-Lass

An würde hier Ursache bedeuten.

Ursache für den Trieb, Ursache für den Reiz, Ursache für den Schub, Ursache für den Lass.

Somit würde ich sagen ja. Antrieb zu Trieb gleich Anreiz zu Reiz

Trieb-Feder, Trieb-Rad, An-Trieb Antriebs-Strang, Trieb-Rad, Trieb-Wagen

Tieb bedeutet im Endeffekt quelle der Bewegung.

Antrieb --> Ursache des Triebs
Trieb --> Vermittler des Triebs vom Antrieb

Comment: Hintrieb, Hinzreiz, Hinschub, Hinlass. Ich habe diese Wörter niei gehört und es gibt sie auch nicht. An bedeutet also nicht hin. Ursache auch nicht. Mein Antrieb zu jagen könnte Hunger sein. Hunger selbst ist der Trieb und die Ursache meines Handelns - wieso sollte das in dem "An" stecken? Die Ursache des Hungers interessiert gar nicht, wenn ich sage, dass der Hunger mein Antrieb zur Jagd ist. Quelle der Bewegung ist es auch nicht, denn nicht jeder Trieb führt zur Bewegung. Der letzte Satz wäre wohl tautologisch, wenn er irgendeinen Sinn machen würde: Trieb->Vermitteler des Triebs vom Antrieb.

Comment: @userunknown Vielleicht wurde das in dieser Antwort etwas kurz angebunden ausgedrueckt. _An bedeutet hin_ war nicht so gemeint, dass diese Woerter existieren, sondern dass die Bedeutung von _hin_ in den Woertern mit _An..._ steckt.

Comment: @Zelphir: Wenn ich also sage "Ehrgeiz ist mein Antrieb", was hat es mit dem 'hin' auf sich? Wohin? Wieso nicht woher?