# Empfindlich und seine Synonyme

Tags: word-choice, synonym

> **empfindlich:** 
>       1. auf bestimmte Reize leicht, schnell reagierend
>      2.a.     [seelisch] leicht verletzbar; feinfühlig, sensibel, zartbesaitet
>        2.b.   gereizt, gekränkt; leicht beleidigt, reizbar
>       3.aufgrund einer körperlichen Schwäche anfällig
>       4.aufgrund einer weniger robusten Beschaffenheit leicht zu verderben, zu beschädigen
>
> **feinfühlig:**  fein empfindend, zartfühlend; einfühlsam, sensibel
>
> **sensibel** 
>       1. von besonderer Feinfühligkeit; empfindsam
>       2. (Medizin) empfindlich gegenüber Schmerzen und Reizen von außen; schmerzempfindlich
>       3. besonders viel Sorgfalt, Umsicht, Fingerspitzengefühl o. Ä. erfordernd, heikel

Die Bedeutungen 2 ist der einzige medizinisch benutzt, also kann hier versäumt werden

> **empfindsam:** 
>      a. von feinem, zartem Empfinden; zartfühlend, einfühlsam
>      b. gefühlvoll, sentimental

Quelle: Duden

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Adjektiven?

Comment: Unterschiede hängen auch vom **Kontext** ab, der hier wie bei den meisten deiner Fragen leider fehlt. So können wir dir nur eine Antwort geben, die genau so auch in jedem Wörterbuch unter den Beispielen steht. Falls du mit deinem Wörterbuch und den dortigen Einträgen nicht klarkommst, solltest du uns deine Schwierigkeiten sagen, denn nur so können wir sinnvoll weiterhelfen. Danke schön.

Comment: Wenn ich in meinem Wörterbuch "sensitivity" nachschaue, bekomme ich ein Paar mögliche Wörter. Ich weiß doch nicht, in welchem Kontext welches benutzt werden kann und ob es inhaltliche Unterschiede dazwischen gibt. Siehe z.B. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23567/reiz-und-seine-synonyme

Comment: Das ist andersherum nicht besser: [**empfindlich:**](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=empfindlich&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) sensitive, tender, delicate, susceptible, damageable, huffy, pettish, sever, tetchy, thin-skinned, touchily, touchy, weak, severely. Welches nun richtig ist, hängt vom jeweiligen Kontext ab. Bei den anderen Beispielen ist es nicht so dramatisch, da die Auswahl kleiner ist.

Comment: Ja, aber ich suche in meinem **polnisch-deutschen** Wörterbuch das Wort "wrażliwy". Und welchen soll ich in welchem Kontext nutzen, wenn das alle gleich klingelt?

Answer (score 4):

Alle vier Adjektive haben eine ähnliche Bedeutung und es hilft auch wenig, dass sie vom Duden in ihrer Bedeutung gegenseitig referenziert werden. Dennoch verbindet man im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung mit den Wörtern. Leider ist es nicht so offensichtlich, aber ich versuche es mal zu beschreiben, wie ich die Unterschiede empfinde:

Als *„empfindlich”* wird eine Person beschrieben, die – wie schon in der Definition beschrieben – leicht auf etwas reagiert. Häufig ist der Begriff negativ konnotiert, also ist es meistens keine gute Eigenschaft. Viele Menschen, die besonders empfindlich sind, neigen zu Überreaktionen, sodass man mit ihnen vorsichtig umgehen sollte (beispielsweise um Streit zu vermeiden).

„Feinfühlich“, „sensibel“ und „empfindsam“ gehen schon eher in die gleiche Richtung und beschreiben eine eher positive Eigenschaft einer Person. Häufig geht die Bedeutung auch in Richtung der [Empathie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathie), also der Fähigkeit, sich in andere Personen hineinzuversetzen, deren Gefühle zu verstehen und ihnen dann besonders gut beistehen zu können. „Feinfühlig” würde ich es dabei eher benutzen, wenn die Person mit Vorsicht vorgeht, also sich beispielsweise nur langsam, in kleinen Schritten an eine andere Person herantastet (bildlich gesprochen). „Empfindsam” bezieht sich häufig auch auf die Person selbst, also wenn sie beispielsweise bei Problemen anderer schnell mitfühlt. Zum Beispiel, wenn eine gute Freundin traurig ist, dann würde eine empfindsame Person eventuell auch traurig werden. „Sensibel” ist für mich eher so etwas dazwischen: Also jemand der mitfühlend ist, aber sich trotzdem vorsichtig und empatisch verhält, aber auch in die Richtung von empfindlich geht.

Ingesamt sind die Unterschiede alles andere als klar, und ich kann Verwirrung absolut verstehen. Aber wenn du in einer Situation bist, in der du einen der Begriffe benötigst, dann ist es vermutlich weniger wichtig, welchen der Begriffe du benutzt, da sie alle in die gleiche Richtung gehen.

Comment: Und welcher der Begriffe würde hier am besten passen: "Das Gedicht zu verstehen benötigt eine besondere [sensitivity]"?

Comment: @marmistrz... was würdest du denn nachdem du die Antwort gelesen hast, denken?

Comment: Eher *Empfindsamkeit*. Bin aber nicht sicher.

Comment: Ich verstehe zwar nicht so viel von Gedichten, aber das klingt ganz gut ;)